# Generating DDL and DML statements from existing tables in MS Access 2016

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have created database using MS Access 2016. I was thinking that it will easy to generate DDL and DML statements after that like it is in other tools such as MySQL and MS SQL Server but unfortunately this is not the case.

I have tried using DBWscript but that is not built for Access 2016 yet.

Please suggest something.